Usage of "prorsus ut" (idiom?)
I don't quite understand the following clause from the Historia Augusta:
...prorsus ut autem patrem militibus praeberet ("so he showed himself to be much like a father to his troops")
Apparently prorsus ut autem is some kind of idiom which I don't understand. Like, if you read it literally it says "(extremely) so however" ... which does not make too much sense in this context. How should I interpret this use of prorsus?

For what it's worth, the Loeb Classical Library has prorsus autem ut. Either way, I don't really see the problem, would it not be perfectly good English to say "just so that, however, he proved to be a father to the soldiers"?
